# Turtlebot with not the same model irobot

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have two turtlebots which are of the 4XXX series. I need to define the port number and the baud rate. But, I do not know how to do this. The turtlebots are built around the 5XX and the i-create.  Any advice would be nice, please.

Thank You in Advance.

:-)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11631/turtlebot-with-not-the-same-model-irobot/) by [MovieMaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/1184/moviemaker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-10-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

if you look in the code you will see a call for setting the baud rate in turtlebot_driver.py... create the SCI interface with the desired baud (something like self.sci= SerialCommandInterface(tty, YOURBAUD)) which basically calls serial with the baudrate

if you would like to change the baudrate and port at a higher level change the turtlebot launch file to use the desire port and baud rate. both parameters are exposed at the node level in turtlebot_node.py

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0